# Rangespace of Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse : $\mathcal{R}(A^+)=\mathcal{N}(A)^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Let $A$ a m-by-n matrix. $A^+$ its MP pseudoinverse.

Is $\mathcal{R}(A^+)$ the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal{N}(A)$ ?

If yes, how do you prove it ?

I don't think the $AA^+A=A$ and $A^+AA^+=A^+$ properties are enough, since you can find a application mapping $\mathcal{R}(A)$ to a non-orthogonal complement of  $\mathcal{N}(A)$ which also have those properties.

So if it's true, I guess the fact that $AA^+$ is hermitian must be used, but I'm not sure to see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
x=A^+Ax+(x-A^+Ax)
$$
where
$$A(x-A^+Ax)=0 $$
so the space is the sum of $\mathcal{R}(A^+)$ and $\mathcal{N}(A)$.

The ortogonality of the two spaces is also easy.

If $A=UDV$ is his SVD decomposition, then 
$$v\in \mathcal{N}(A)\iff UDVv=0\iff D(Vv)=0\iff Vv=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\*\end{pmatrix}$$
We have also $A^+=V^tD^+U^t$, so, given any $v\in \mathcal{N}(A)$, and any $w=A^+z\in \mathcal{R}(A^+)$, we have
$$ w^tv=z^t(A^+)^tv=z^tUD^+Vv=0$$
thus proving the ortogonality

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is SVD absolutely necessary ?

Comment: it was my definition of pseudoinverse. I didn't know there was a characterization only through his properties  XD